# Prestashop migration - broken URL, bad redirect, and can't reset admin password / access back-end office

Tags: url, migration, prestashop, forgot-password

So I have a local copy of prestashop (~Sites/shop) and my /etc/hosts set up so that 'localhost/shop' lets me develop on it. I'm ready to push it to the server, where its temporary spot is (http://66.206.84.189/~walnutci/shop). It isn't an entire site, just the shop sub-pages. The main site content will need to be static, so I need this contained within the 'shop' folder.

I tarred the thing up, moved it into my /shop subfolder, created an empty database of the same name as my local copy with a identically named user and permissions, imported the database (so I shouldn't have to mess with config/settings.inc.php) and...

Home page redirects me to localhost/shop, my local copy. So, I go try to log in to change it in Preferences > SEO&URL and http://66.206.84.189...hop/adminfolder properly forwards me to back-end log in. However, it's not taking my admin email and password. Same database != same credentials? I updated it with

```
UPDATE ps_employee SET passwd = md5('7uSpY718uKjnAOOH367gbVzzjm5StzLyfIBpSDsdI5FwxVq84UD4tPdMpassword') WHERE email = 'me@mycompany.com';
```

and zilch. I hit Enter at it refreshes the page, ignoring my input. The URL displays the email address I'm trying to log in with, but no red error. If I put in garbage for the password it throws the proper error "wrong password". My password, and manually updating it in the database work fine locally.

So, am I manually updating my admin password wrong? Can I hard-code the site URL somehow? I thought by keeping the folder names the same and using my Apache /etc/hosts I wouldn't run into any redirection errors (Friendly URLs are turned off, so there is no .htaccess anywhere).

Running 1.4.6.2. Mac OSX 10.7.2 locally, server is CentOS 5.7.

Thank you so much. I threw up a post to Prestashop a while back, kept looking over the weekend, and still haven't figured it out. Appreciate any ideas / insight.

Comment: Make sure there aren't any occurrences of `localhost` in your database when you migrated it. Also, `/etc/hosts` isn't Apache, but a system-wide configuration file.

Comment: Good catch, Blender. I manually update ps_configuration table, setting ps_shop_domain = "66.206.84.189/~walnutci". This was a headache only in that I can't log in to the back-end. I still can't, btw. But the fact that I can at least test in other browsers now is great. I'm wondering if there security aspects of an installation that are dependent upon ones environment?

Answer (score 8):

It is quite late for an answer, but i hope it will help someone else.

Prestashop is coded to pull the "site URL" attribute from its database when a request is served and then redirects to that shop URL, if you have moved the database and site to new a server, you need to change the 'site URL" value. To do so access your database, I use phpmyadmin.

Go to table named ps_shop_url and change the entries for domain and domianssl accordingly. This will change the site URL constants value to your current URL.

note: ps_ is the database prefix for prestashop.

Comment: Also -> `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` in `ps_configuration table`

Comment: I beleive you need to make the changes in BOTH tables. 

`ps_configuration` and `ps_shop_url`

I also followed [these instructions](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/prestashop2/changing-the-prestashop-url-settings)

Answer (score 7):

When you are using **Prestashop 1.6.1.1** and you move your project to another database and server, the changes are:

- To modify `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` values from `ps_configuration` table.
- To modify `physical_uri` value from `ps_shop_url`table.

For example, using XAMPP on Windows (development environment) and supposing you have the project in `htdocs/prestashop/`, the values must be:

- `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN`: `localhost`
- `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL`: `localhost`
- `physical_uri`: `/prestashop/`

Answer (score 2):

this is all correct but dont forget to rewrite Settings->SEO and URL and press "Save"

Same like permlinks in Wordpress.

Answer (score -2):

Hello I have the same problem after the update of my site can not access it. But you say rewrite Settings-> SEO and URL and click "Save" except that I no longer have Access either to my back office.
Here is what appears on the front:
500 server error
Oops, something went wrong.

Try updating this page or feel free to contact us if the problem persists.
and a white page on the back office, I have true in the file defines.inc.php and it displays this:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]
Table 'db756986084.fs16_shop_url' doesn't exist


SELECT s.id_shop, CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri) AS uri, su.domain, su.main
                    FROM fs16_shop_url su
                    LEFT JOIN fs16_shop s ON (s.id_shop = su.id_shop)
                    WHERE (su.domain = 'goundo.fr' OR su.domain_ssl = 'goundo.fr')
                        AND s.active = 1
                        AND s.deleted = 0
                    ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri)) DESC

at line 746 in file classes/db/Db.php
741.         if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
742.             $dbg = debug_backtrace();
743.             WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
744.         } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
745.             if ($sql) {
746.                 throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
747.             }
748. 
749.             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
750.         }
751.     }
DbCore->displayError - [line 378 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 597 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->executeS - [line 344 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 42 - admin/index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```

Bonjour j'ai le même problème après la MAJ de mon site impossible d'y accéder. Mais vous dites de réécrire Paramètres-> SEO et URL et cliquez sur "Enregistrer" sauf que moi je n'ai plus Access non plus a mon back office.
Voici ce qui s'affiche en front:
Erreur 500 serveur
Oups, quelque chose s'est mal passé.

Essayez d'actualiser cette page ou n'hésitez pas à nous contacter si le problème persiste.
et une page blance sur le back office, j'ai true dans le fichier defines.inc.php et ça affiche ça:

[PrestaShopDatabaseException]
Table 'db756986084.fs16_shop_url' doesn't exist

```
SELECT s.id_shop, CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri) AS uri, su.domain, su.main
                    FROM fs16_shop_url su
                    LEFT JOIN fs16_shop s ON (s.id_shop = su.id_shop)
                    WHERE (su.domain = 'goundo.fr' OR su.domain_ssl = 'goundo.fr')
                        AND s.active = 1
                        AND s.deleted = 0
                    ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri)) DESC

at line 746 in file classes/db/Db.php
741.         if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
742.             $dbg = debug_backtrace();
743.             WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
744.         } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
745.             if ($sql) {
746.                 throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
747.             }
748. 
749.             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
750.         }
751.     }
DbCore->displayError - [line 378 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 597 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->executeS - [line 344 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 42 - admin/index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```